# Obtain the html source/text of another webage through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to:

- From within my webpage, get all the HTML source from another webpage. I need to do this in order to pass that other pages html source to my function.

The following different attempts don't work:

```
var html = $.get("http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/braised_turkey_legs/").html();
var html = $.get("http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/braised_turkey_legs/");
var html = $("http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/braised_turkey_legs/").html();
```

Comment: I believe you're running into the Same Origin Policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ajax, and get is just a shortcut for ajax, it's not really possible to get the source html from other domains, if that is what your trying to do? as ajax has a same origin policy for security reasons.

However going thru YQL it is possible to do is, read [this](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/) to see how, or you could proxy with php or something else, with just regular get requests however it's not doable.

If the pages you are trying to get are on your domain, .load(); would probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), this is what's holding you back.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `get` function does not return the loaded data - rather, it calls a callback function and passes the data as a parameter.

This is from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

P.S.: Note that in any case this will only work on the same domain, as cross-domain AJAX is normally not supported for security reasons.